# Why I don't have data from the database?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I am developing an ASP.NET web-based application and I am using a Telerik tool with it. Everything works fine even in the production server in my company. Now, we have another server that we are using it for testing the web-based applications that we are developing. I copied my application including its database from the production server to this testing server, but it did not work well on it. it opens the website but there is no data from the database and I don't know why? I have the `connectionstring` in the web.config file and I have the same things that are in the production server but still there is no data.

I did not change anything in the application and I am using .NET 4 and it is installed in the both servers. Everything is the same but I don't know why I am getting this error. Do you have any solution to this problem?

**Why the application works in the first server and does not work in the second one?**

My web.config file is:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add connectionString="Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PMODServices;Integrated Security=True" name="PMODServicesConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
         <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
                <add assembly="System.Management, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
            <!--    <add assembly="office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>  -->
                <add assembly="stdole, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" /></assemblies>
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <httpHandlers>
            <!-- <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" validate="false" />-->
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" validate="false" />
            <add path="ChartImage.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" validate="false" />
            <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" verb="*" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" validate="false" />
            <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />
        </httpHandlers>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>

        <pages>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" />
        </httpModules>
    </system.web>

    <location path="Users/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
            <system.web>
                <authorization>
                    <allow users="*"/>
                </authorization>
            </system.web>
        </location>
        <location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
            <system.web>
                <authorization>
                    <allow users="*"/>
                </authorization>
            </system.web>
        </location>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ChartImage_axd" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" />
            <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" />
            <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        </handlers>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="RadUploadModule" />
            <remove name="RadCompression" />
            <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadHttpModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="RadCompression" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompression" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Telerik.ScriptManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
        <add key="Telerik.StyleSheetManager.TelerikCdn" value="Enabled" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the event logs?  Are you 100% sure the connection string is accurate?  Does the dev server have a database installed?

Comment: Yes dude but I only have a minor error with the telerik tool that says: Telerik is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling telerik or putting the assemblies in GAC?As far as I remember , telerik needs more assemblies than you added in VS as reference to run properly.

Comment: Could you please give more information about this? Where I can find the GAC? I just add some references in the assemblies in the web.config file.

Comment: GAC ( Global Assembly Cache ) is located at "C:\Windows\assembly". If you install Telerik on your development server, the setup process will copy required assemblies to the GAC.